# Text processing function for removing punctuation

Tags: python, function, nlp, text-processing

Please write a function that replaces all characters that the user provides by empty spaces.

The function is:

- Is called `clean_text_general()`;
- Has one positional parameter `text`;
- Has one keyword parameter `chars_to_remove`, which is a set *(set the default to `{'\n', ',', '.', '"'}`)*;
- Returns a string, e.g., the cleaned text

When the user provides a different value to `chars_to_remove`, e.g., `{'a'}`, then only those characters should be replaced by empty spaces in the text.

Here is my code so far:

```py
def clean_text_general(text, chars_to_remove=text.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').replace('\n', '').replace('"', '')):
    text = text(chars_to_remove(text))
    print(text)

clean_text(a_story,chars_to_remove=text.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').replace('\n', '').replace('"', ''))
```

The input can be any string.

Comment: Set `chars_to_remove='\n,."'` and then iterate over `chars_to_remove` and call `.replace()` for every char and re-assign `text` with return of `.replace()` every iteration. Don't forget to `return text` after loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise the *maketrans* and *translate* string functions like this:

```
import string

def clean_text_general(s):
    return s.translate(s.maketrans({k: ' ' for k in string.punctuation}))

print(clean_text_general('a,b.c'))
```

**Output:**

```
a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
def clean_text_general(text, chars_to_remove={'\n', ',', '.', '"'}):
    return text.translate(text.maketrans({k: '' for k in chars_to_remove}))
```

Example:

```
>>> clean_text_general('hello, world.\n')
'hello world'
>>> clean_text_general('hello, world.\n', chars_to_remove={'\n', ','})
'hello world.'
```

If you don't feel comfortable using `str.translate` and `str.maketrans` then you can use this one (it's less efficient):

```
def clean_text_general(text, chars_to_remove={'\n', ',', '.', '"'}):
    for c in chars_to_remove:
        text = text.replace(c, '')
    return text
```

Comment: But `set` is mutable.

Comment: @OlvinRoght So what? I don't understand your point

Comment: Quote from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values): *"**Important warning**: The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes."*

Comment: @OlvinRoght Ok I'm aware of that but the OP asked exactly for a set. This is probably some homework, nothing to be put in production

Comment: So will be good to add this warning in your answer :)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Feel free to edit my answer and to add any useful comment you want to provide